# replace all characters numeric in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

how I can replace all characters numeric with space or just deleting 
these characters

```
  {{  city|replace({ 'all characters numeric ' : ' ' }) }}
```

Comment: https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions#pcre you can add this to your project and use the preg_replace.

Answer (score -1):

A quick solution is to just list in the replace filter all digits

```
{{  'Stack 12 over 74 5001 flow'|replace({ '0' : '','1' : '','2' : '','3' : '','4' : '','5' : '','6' : '','7' : '','8' : '','9' : '' }) }}
```

Or you can use **regex**,
take a look [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/use-regex-in-replace-filter)

Comment: It may OK, resolves the problem but it can be relatively slow. https://github.com/jasny/twig-extensions#pcre this may be a good solution.